# Uploading file with Python and Alfresco API

Tags: python, curl, upload, alfresco

I'm facing a problem with Alfresco and Python : I want to upload a new file directly with Python. Each time I try I get a HTTP 500 error with no details ...

I first try with CURL just to be sure that it works and the file is uploaded without problems.

I used the following curl command line:

```
url -X POST -uadmin:admin "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload" -F filedata=@/tmp/eeeeee.pdf -F siteid=test -F containerid=documentLibrary
```

In my Python script I tried PyCurl and now the simple urllib. I think the problem come from the way the file is given as parameter.

Python code using PyCurl:

```
c = pycurl.Curl()
params = {'containerid': 'documentLibrary', 'siteid': 'test', 'filedata': open('/tmp/eeeeee.pdf', 'rb')}
c.setopt(c.URL, 'http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload')
c.setopt(c.POST, 1)
c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, urllib.urlencode(params))
c.setopt(c.USERPWD, 'admin:admin')
c.perform()
```

This code sample leads to :

```
 {
    "code" : 500,
    "name" : "Internal Error",
    "description" : "An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request."
  },  

  "message" : "04200017 Unexpected error occurred during upload of new content."
```

Does someone know how to achieve that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the `curl` command you use. Please also inlcude the failing Python code. Does the Alfresco log contain an error message?

Comment: Thanks, post edited ! No error message in the log, just that : ::1 - - [21/May/2015:10:08:49 +0200] "POST /alfresco/service/api/upload HTTP/1.1" 500 6580

Comment: That looks like a line from the access log. Take a look into the `catalina.out` log file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the very simple library [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
import json
import requests

url = "http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/upload"
auth = ("admin", "admin")
files = {"filedata": open("/tmp/foo.txt", "rb")}
data = {"siteid": "test", "containerid": "documentLibrary"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, auth=auth)
print(r.status_code)
print(json.loads(r.text))
```

Output:

```
200
{'fileName': 'foo.txt',
 'nodeRef': 'workspace://SpacesStore/37a96447-44b0-4aaa-b6ff-98dae1f12a73',
 'status': {'code': 200,
  'description': 'File uploaded successfully',
  'name': 'OK'}}
```

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks for the code. Did you know why it is not working with pycurl ?

Comment: No. And without the error message from the Alfresco log file it is hard to tell.